# iOS - Unit testing a viewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller

So I am unit testing my ViewController, and as soon as it calls viewDidLoad my test crashes, because in my code I try to add a barButtonItem to my navigationBar and it does not exist.

How can I make this separation while unit testing my viewController

**EDIT:**
It crashes on the second line, any suggestions? so it's not a navigationBar because at this point I haven't added my toolbar to my navigationBar yet

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init]; 
[toolBar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

**EDIT:** I am running `SenTestCase`s and I get no exception traces

[image]

Comment: Adding a `UIBarButtonItem` to a `nil` `navigationBar` shouldnt blow up.. should it?

Comment: I think more information is needed. What is the crash you experience? What sort of test is this and how are you running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the controller has constructed it's view first. Accessing the [view property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on `UIViewController` should trigger the creation of the `UIView` it's controlling: `[mycontroller view]`.